# Use Apache authentication + authorization to control access to Subversion subdirectories

Tags: apache-2.2, unix, svn, ldap

I have a single SVN repo at /var/svn/ with a few subdirectories. Staff must be able to access the top-level directory and all subdirectories within it, but I want to restrict access to subdirectories using alternate htpasswd files.

This works for our Staff.

```
<Location />
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /var/svn

AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap

# mod_authnz_ldap
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
AuthLDAPURL "ldap.example.org:636/ou=people,ou=Unit,ou=Host,o=ldapsvc,dc=example,dc=org?uid?sub?(objectClass=PosixAccount)"
AuthLDAPGroupAttribute memberUid
AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off

Require ldap-group cn=staff,ou=PosixGroup,ou=Unit,ou=Host,o=ldapsvc,dc=example,dc=org
</Location>
```

Now, I am trying to restrict access to a subdirectory with a separate htpasswd file, like this:

```
<Location /customerA>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /var/svn

# mod_authn_file
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /usr/local/etc/apache22/htpasswd.customerA
Require user customerA
</Location>
```

I can use Firefox and curl to browse to this folder fine:

```
curl https://svn.example.org/customerA/ --user customerA:password
```

But I cannot use check out this SVN repository:

```
$ svn co https://svn.example.org/customerA/
svn: Repository moved permanently to 'https://svn.example.org/customerA/'; please relocate
```

And on the server logs, I get this strange error:

```
# httpd-access.log
192.168.19.13 - - [03/May/2010:16:40:00 -0700] "OPTIONS /customerA HTTP/1.1" 401 401
192.168.19.13 - customerA [03/May/2010:16:40:00 -0700] "OPTIONS /customerA HTTP/1.1" 301 244

# httpd-error.log
[Mon May 03 16:40:00 2010] [error] [client 192.168.19.13] Could not fetch resource information.  [301, #0]
[Mon May 03 16:40:00 2010] [error] [client 192.168.19.13] Requests for a collection must have a trailing slash on the URI.  [301, #0]
```

My questions:

1. Can I restrict access to Subversion
   subdirectories using Apache access
   controls? DocumentRoot is commented
   out, so it's not clear that the FAQ
   at
   http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#http-301-error
   applies.
2. I prefer to not use AuthzSVNAccessFile, because it doesn't support LDAP groups. We control access using LDAP, and make heavy use of LDAP groups.

Comment: I earned the Tumbleweed badge for this!

Answer (score 1):

I've just spent all afternoon trying to do it, and I think the answer to question 1 as you've asked it is "no".  If I try it and look in the error log, I see errors on PROPFIND requests for paths like "/myrepo/!svn":  i.e., I think the Subversion client is sometimes requesting magic paths that only have meaning to the Subversion server module, as opposed to paths like "/myrepo/subdir" that Apache could understand and restrict.

The fact that you're using SVNParentPath, however, makes me suspect that /var/svn actually contains multiple Subversion repositories, and customerA is one such repository.  You can tell by checking if there is a file /var/svn/customerA/format.

Is that correct?  If so, you can set up a VirtualHost or another location where you can access just the customerA repository using the SVNPath directive.  For example:

```
<VirtualHost>
  ServerName customerA.example.com

  <Location />
     SVNPath /var/svn/customerA
     ...
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```